# Using "held" for future events

Tags: tenses, past-participles

I feel like I've seen cases where the verb "held" is used for a future event, as in

> I will attend the World English Conference held on January 10-15,
>   2017.

And I found the same sentence in an ESL textbook recently. However, I can't figure out what that "held" is doing; it seems to me that the grammar should more accurately be "will be held" (future passive), but I also feel like I've seen this pattern before. Is this an alternative use of "held", or is it more likely just an error in the book (and in other places)?

Comment: What makes you think "will be held" can replace "held"? How many verbs are there in the sentence if you use "will be held"?

Comment: Ranthony: sorry, I meant "that will be held" or "which will be held".

Answer (score 1):

*Held* is a past participle modifying WEC.  And, as you've figured out, combined with a date certain it refers to past time.  So it's use is inapt in 2016 to describe a conference not scheduled until 2017.  There are a number of ways to make this sensible.  If you want to keep a participle:

> I will attend the World English Conference **being held** on January 10-15, 2017.

You may use an infinitive:

> I will attend the World English Conference **to be held** on January 10-15, 2017.

Or you may use a finite verb in the future tense by using a relative clause:

> I will attend the World English Conference which **will be held** on January 10-15, 2017.

Note that *held* is acceptable to describe regularly-scheduled events:

> I will attend the World English Conference held in the first month of odd-numbered years.

Comment: That all makes a lot of sense to me. I'm tempted to think that the textbook is simply wrong, as I would definitely prefer any of the alternatives you've offered to the original.

Answer (score 0):

The conference held on January 10-15, 2017 is short for a relative clause
The conference that will be held on January... The verb has the basic forms hold held held.